# Swift printing double as int

Tags: swift

This is my code and I can't figure out how I can make my print in a `int` format instead of a `double`. If I change it to an `int`, my if statements won't work which is why its currently a `double`.

Is there a way I can print a `double` as a `int`?

```
import UIKit

var strValue = box1.text
var floatValue = Double((strValue as NSString).integerValue)
var strValue2 = box2.text
var floatValue2 = Double((strValue2 as NSString).integerValue)
var text = "1"
var procent = floatValue2 / floatValue * 100

if floatValue < 99 {
    box3.text = " \(floatValue) " // How can "floatvalue" be printed as "xx" and not "xx.xx"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm not at a computer capable of running Xcode at this time, so I'm going from my memory.

If you want to print the double as an int, but not change all of your variables to Integers, you may be able to just do this:

```
import UIKit

var strValue = box1.text
var floatValue = Double((strValue as NSString).integerValue)
var strValue2 = box2.text
var floatValue2 = Double((strValue2 as NSString).integerValue)
var text = "1"
var procent = floatValue2 / floatValue * 100

if floatValue < 99
{
box3.text = " \(Int(floatValue)) " // Notice the Int(floatValue). This casts the floatValue to an Integer.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use String format method to format your double as you wish:

```
let myDouble = 23.12

box3.text = String(format: "%.0f", myDouble)   // "23"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var strValue = "13.45"
var floatValue = Double(strValue) ?? Double.NaN
var strValue2 = "23.45"
var floatValue2 = Double(strValue2) ?? Double.NaN
var text = "1"
var procent = floatValue2 / floatValue * 100

if floatValue < 99
{
print(" \(Int(round(floatValue))) ")
}
```

This assumes that NaN is a reasonable default when the text in the box isn’t a valid number. You might also choose to handle missing / invalid text more explicitly, as in the example below.

I’m also assuming that you want to do the math as FP, *then* round the result to int. But the `procent` variable wasn’t ever used, so perhaps you only need to do math with ints:

```
var strValue = "13"
var strValue2 = "23"
if let floatValue = Int(strValue), let floatValue2 = Int(strValue2)
{
    if floatValue < 99
    {
        print(" \(Int(floatValue)) ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul Cantrell as well, it was the (int ) I needed to know about, this fixed the problem. I feel like you gave me some great tips, however I know so little about Swift and programming, that I  (to be honest) have no clue what you mean.. when you say NaN or FP.. I'm kind of lost. But thanks for helping, appreciate it!

Comment: NaN means “not a number.” It is not Swift-specific; it’s available most everywhere you floating point arithmetic, all the way back to C. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Answer (score 0):

Setup for test:

```
let box1 = UILabel()
box1.text = "23.23"
```

Conversion code:

```
let strValue = box1.text!
let strFormatted = String(format: "%.0f", Double(strValue)!)   // "23"

print("strFormatted: \(strFormatted)") // strFormatted: 23
```